# Declaring classes in C++ constructor for another class reports "No matching function"

Tags: c++, arduino

Please be gentle... I don't do much C++ and am trying to tidy up some code.

I'm trying to compile the code below in Arduino Studio, and it keeps throwing an error:

> no matching function for call to 'devPort::devPort()'

on the following line:

`Sensor(String type, float adjustment, devPort port) {`

I've tried moving the `devPort` part to a new `.cpp` file and `#include`'ing it, but I get the same error.

I also tried:

`Sensor(String type, float adjustment, devPort::devPort port)`

But still the same error.

```cpp
 class devPort { // There will be 10 'Port's, all pre-defined as unavailable until the boardtype is known
    public:
      devPort(String name, int pin1, int pin2, int mode) {
        this->name = name;
        this->pin1 = pin1;
        this->pin2 = pin2;
        this->mode = mode;
      }
      String name;
      int pin1;
      int pin2;
      int mode;  // -1 = Disabled, 0 = SDA/SCL, 1=DAC, 2=ADC, 3=GPIO
  };
 
  

  // The 'Sensor's will be stored in the flash memory 
  class Sensor {
    public:
      Sensor(String type, float adjustment, devPort port) {   // <--- This is where it complains
        this->type = type;
        this->adjustment = adjustment;
        this->port = port;
      }
      String type;        // Derived from *sensorTypes
      float adjustment;   // +/- adjustment value 
      devPort port;       // Custom Port
  };
```

I would expect that it should just allow this (and I've tried moving them above/below each other in case of linear compilation).

Comment: `devPort` doesn't have a default constructor. You can use [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

Comment: member are initialized before the constructor runs

Comment: -> `Sensor(String type, float adjustment, devPort port) : type(type),adjustment(adjustment),port(port) {}`

Comment: I recommend initializing your member variables.  Rather than letting them be implicitly default initialized, and then assigned in the constructor's body.

Comment: The distinction between initialization and assignment is very significant in C++.

Comment: `Sensor(String type, float adjustment, devPort port) : type(type),adjustment(adjustment),port(port) {}`  solved it... but an explaination (in plain 'I don't know **** about C++' language) would be useful for me and others :-)

Comment: the explanation is in the duplicate you find on the top. Or really any introduction to constructors must mention it. Though dont worry, there are just too many poor tutorials out there, and I am rather sure that this is the most important detail that is overlooked by almost any beginner until they hit the error you face.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor